# Scheduled task runs in Intellij but not using mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application where I have done all the things correctly for scheduling as evidenced by the fact that when I run within Intellij the scheduled task does get invoked, so I'm not bothering to paste my code here. This is on a development machine. But the same code when I run it on the runtime machine from command line with mvn spring-boot:run it never invokes the scheduled task. I don't have lazy init set to true in my application.properties. I have no   clue what to do now. Any ideas?

Comment: Check maven versions (may be different). Alternatively, try `mvn clean compile spring-boot:run`

Comment: How have you specified scheduled task? Using cron, fixed rate, fixed delay?

Comment: My pom.xml specifies 2.6.1 for springboot, so it should be the same in both environments. I'm using fixed delay.

Comment: mvn clean compile spring-boot:run did it. Thanks Kypps.

Comment: @HughDarling, consider adding the solution as an answer and accepting it or just delete the question. Thanks!

Comment: Let Kypps add his comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mvn clean compile spring-boot:run

fixed the issue, although I don't know why.